# Django ListView retrieve model fields specific to a user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

New to Django, so please bear with me...

I have a list of comments made by users on articles posted to a site.  For each comment I give the name of the user that posted it.  *I want it so that when you click on the username that it will take you to a list of all of that user's comments.*  However, I can't figure out how to specify that in my `views.py` file.

Here is the code that make the list with the links to user names:

```
{% for comment in article.comments.all %}
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ comment }}
            <div class="Link-detail">
                <a href="{% url 'Article:by_user' comment.author%}">
                 @{{ comment.author }}
                 </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

When you click on the link it takes you to the correct url as specified in the `urls.py` file, so no problems there.

The template is working fine and I loop through comments as such:

```
{% for comment in comment_list %}
    <li>{{ comment.text }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

And I think the model is correct:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='comments', 
              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='usercomments', 
              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['-created_date']
```

So, here is where I get lost:

```
class UserComments(ListView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = "news/user_comment_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'comment_list'
```

I get the class-based view set up as a `ListView`, pull in the `model`, assign a `template_name`, and a `context_object_name`, but I can't figure out how to filter it such that the information returned to `context_object_name` is filtered to the list that corresponds to the name of the comment.author that was clicked on.
What do I have to do to grab that link name and use it in a filter?
How should that filter be structured?

Comment: Note that `comment_list` is the default context object name for the `Comment` model, so you can remove that line if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `get_queryset` and filter the queryset using the username from the url. You can access keyword arguments from the url from `self.kwargs`.

```
class UserComments(LoginRequewdListView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = "news/user_comment_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'comment_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(UserComments, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(author__username=self.kwargs['username'])
```

You may have to adjust the filter slightly depending on your URL pattern.

Comment: That worked.  Just had to change the (user__username==...) part to (author__username==...)

Answer (score 0):

You can override `get_context_data()`. For detail see [documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) Hope this helps !